# Apache2 doesn't work on my new Mac Snow Leopard installation (Mac OS X 10.6.4)

Tags: apache2, osx-snow-leopard

I've installed snow leopard on the old tiger and I tried to run apache2 by clicking system preferences->sharing->web sharing. It seems to run but if I try to access http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1 or http://192.168.1.6/ (my ip on my network) it doesn't work. I don't know where is the log file (no files on /private/var/log/apache2/). I've seen that the port in /etc/httpd.conf is 80. But I cannot see the process on Activity Monitoring panel: there is not any httpd or apache process running...

Comment: I used MAMP as suggested Brandon for first. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the answer you are looking for, but MAMP seems to run relatively well for me.

You can also try

```
sudo apachectl start
```

from the command line.

Comment: did the command give any output? and if you ps aux from the command line, you can't see the process?

Comment: sudo apachectl start give me the result org.apache.httpd: Already loaded, but I cannot see any process named httpd o apache. If I write from the command line ps aux | grep httpd I cannot see the process!!!

Comment: may want to try sudo apachectl restart, check your httpd.conf file to make sure you are setup with localhost, and make sure your browser isn't misinterpreting your http://localhost directive. *cough* mamp

Comment: How can I check that I am set up with localhost?

Comment: make sure your servername is localhost in httpd.conf, and Listen is set to 80.

Comment: ServerName localhost:80 then sudo apachectl restart ... but it doesn't work sigh! Listen 80

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find a detailed answer to your question at this URL:

```
http://shapeshed.com/journal/setting_up_local_websites_on_snow_leopard/
```

The "trick" is this line, ... which stops and then restarts apache,

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

This forces apache2 to read any changes you've made to config files.

Also, check to make sure you are using the right config file.
Under Mac OS X 10.6.4, my config files seem to be here:

```
/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Logs files are found here:

```
/var/log/apache2/access_log
```

This should get you up and running, ... but I would also recommend looking into using MAMP, which is a pre-packaged Mac+Apache2+MySQL+PHP5 stack that you can get up and running very quickly.

```
http://www.mamp.info/
```