# Mac Apache2 webserver won't stay available on wireless network

Tags: apache2, osx-snow-leopard

I'm running Apache2 on Mac OS X 10.6.8 on a Mac Mini running at 2 GHz with 4 GB RAM and tons of available space on the hard drive.  I'm trying to connect to the webserver with my iPhone or other devices on my local wireless network to view the webpages I'm working on.  This works perfectly for 5-10 minutes after I restart the Mac Mini, but then the server stops responding and I get various messages on my phone such as:

```
"Safari could not open the page because the server stopped responding"
```

This only occurs over wireless (192.168.x.x), I can still see the pages locally on the Mac.  I found a good tutorial from here:
[Apache2 doesn't work on my new Mac Snow Leopard installation (Mac OS X 10.6.4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008804/apache2-doesnt-work-on-my-new-mac-snow-leopard-installation-mac-os-x-10-6-4)

I've followed the instructions found above at:
http://shapeshed.com/setting_up_local_websites_on_snow_leopard/ and I can successfully see the website created in the instructions for the same 5-10 minutes (after restarting the Mac) or so before I get the same errors.

Restarting Apache doesn't fix the problem, the only way to make it work (for a while), is to restart the Mac.  According to http://oscartheduck.wordpress.com/2007/04/25/session-cache-is-not-configured-hint-sslsessioncache-freebsd/ the session cache warning in the log entry below is a red herring.

A typical log entry is:

```
[Sat Mar 31 12:32:54 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Mar 31 12:33:29 2012] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using username.local for ServerName
[Sat Mar 31 12:33:31 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Mar 31 12:33:31 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Sat Mar 31 12:33:31 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 PHP/5.3.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Mar 31 13:50:21 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Mar 31 13:50:21 2012] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
[Sat Mar 31 13:50:21 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Mar 31 13:50:21 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Sat Mar 31 13:50:21 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 PHP/5.3.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

I've downloaded and tried MAMP, but that didn't work either.  But honestly, I didn't know what to do with it.

I'm reasonably confident this isn't a router problem, I had IIS configured in WinXP to do the same thing and it worked for days on end without hiccups.  Unfortunately, I know a lot more about WinXP than I do about Mac OS X, so this could simply be something I don't understand.  Since I'm working on iPhone development, I kind of need this working on the Mac.

Because someone is going to ask, yes, I enabled Web Sharing in Apple > System Preferences > Sharing.

I originally though this could be a hardware issue with the Airport card, but I've observed absolutely no other problems connecting to the router over wireless, so I don't think so.

I'm into my 4th or 5th day of trying to make this work properly, so any assistance would be gratefully accepted.  I can provide more Apache logs, configuration files, whatever, so I can get this resolved.  Fortunately it's not all that difficult to simply restart the Mac to test the latest stuff I'm working on, but it seems silly to have to do that.  Of course the obvious workaround is to load the stuff onto my WinXP laptop and have it served out from there, but that just seems stupid.

And just FYI, I'm not looking to serve pages to the internet, just locally on devices connected to my wireless router.  I know I can serve pages over the internet if I want to with Apache, but that's not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: We can see where your server went down and came back up ( `[Sat Mar 31 13:50:21 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down` ).  Was that when you restarted the mac, or did that happen without your restarting it?

Comment: @slashingweapon That was probably me doing a "sudo apachectl restart".  I can experiment with Apache restarts and Mac restarts if that'll give you more info?  Thanks for helping.

Comment: So I tried changing the ServerName in /etc/apach2/httpd from the default of "www.example.com" to my machine's 192.168.x.x address and restarting Apache again.  At first it looked hopeful, but it was just reloading from cache I think (I'm working with offline cache so I have to be careful).  Now I'm getting:    `Safari cannot open the page because it could not connect to the server`

Comment: Put the old config back.  You might have put Apache into a state where it couldn't even start up.  Try increasing the log verbosity with `LogLevel info` or even `LogLevel debug`, and maybe it will give you a clue as to why it is shutting down.

Comment: @slashingweapon  I decided to do a scorched earth approach.  I clean-installed Snow Leopard, upgraded to Lion, enabled Web Sharing and bumped the LogLevel to debug.  Exact same behavior and nothing in the logs to indicate why.  I tailed the log and let it hibernate while at lunch.  When it came back up, it didn't have a connection to wireless network yet, so nothing worked.  Once it did, I hit my site from my phone for almost exactly 10 minutes at which point it died as before.  However, I've found that I can simply stop & start WiFi, to get service back (for 10 minutes).

Comment: So, this isn't a fix, but it's a workaround.  I created an alias that lets me quickly cycle my wireless connection:

`alias apcycle='networksetup -setairportpower en1 off; networksetup -setairportpower en1 on'` 
 
This cycles the wifi connection off and on and allows me to carry on with testing.  It's not the solution I'd like, but until I can figure out what's going on, it'll work.